# Building a Quadratic Calculator Program, Roots not right nor is answer

Tags: javascript, quadratic, code.org

I've been learning about quadratic formulas and have been working on Quadratics. I decided to make a program to help me and because I'm bored, and I can't find what is wrong. I'm using code.org's game lab

I've tried to use different versions of squaring and square roots but couldn't figure it out.

```
var a = prompt("What is A? ");
var b = prompt("What is B? ");
var c = prompt("What is C? ");
var x = prompt("What is your x value? ");
var verx = 0;
var very = 0;
var dop = prompt("Are you trying to find the root or the y of an x? ");

var y = 0;
var neg = 0;
function draw(){
  background("white");
  ans();

}
function ans(){
  if(dop == "root"){
    x = [-b+Math.sqrt(b^2-(4*a*c))]/2*a;
    neg = [-b-Math.sqrt(b^2-(4*a*c))]/2*a;
    text("The positive root is " + x, 100, 200);
    text("The negative root is " + neg, 100, 250);
  }
  if(dop == "y"){
    verx = (-b)/(2*a);
    very = ((a*Math.pow(verx, 2)) + (b *verx) + c);
    y = ((a*Math.pow(x, 2))+(b*x)+c);
    text("Vertex ( " + verx + ", " + very + " )", 100, 220);
    text("When x is " + x + " y is " + y, 100, 200);

  }
}
```

I expect the root and y value to be correct, but the only correct thing is my x vertex value.

Comment: You cant use square brackets for grouping terms like you sometimes can in math, since it means something different in javascript; you have to just use more parenthesis instead, ie, `x = (-b+Math.sqrt(b^2-(4*a*c)))/2*a;`

Comment: Also `^` doesnt exponentiate stuff in javascript you have to `b*b` or `Math.pow(b,2)` or `b**2`

Comment: It still doesn't work. I plugged 4 in for a 2 in for b and -1 for c and the answer is 0.309... and -0.809... but I get 4.944... and -12.944...

Comment: Still have an order of operations error. You need to put parenthesis around the `2*a`, otherwise it divides by `2` then _multiplies_ by a, so `x = (-b+Math.sqrt(b^2-(4*a*c)))/(2*a);`